# Box2d Android Game Programming

Tags: android, opengl-es, box2d, game-engine, game-physics

I want to create a physics based game by using box2d game engine.
I dont want to use any engines like cocos2d or libgdx or andengine,etc.
But only box2d.

It is a android game.

I have some doubts?.

1.Is it possible to create a game only using box2d physics engine?
  No any other engine.
2.OR using android canvas with box2d?
3.OR using opengl with box2d?
4.Is box2d nice?
5.Angry birds is created by box2d. But do it only use box2d or anyother engine?.

If any of these is possible then, answer my Questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Box2D alone in your game/app to simulate physics, but without input, drawing capabilities etc, how you will represent it on the screen and interact.

1 - You can create a project that has only box2D added to it, but you are limited to what you can achieve with it. See later answers for more insight to why.

2 - possible but why you would like to do that.

3 - every engine like libgdx, cocos2dx uses OpenGL to draw to the screen. Using raw OpenGL would mean you have pretty much recreate what those engines are doing, so you would have to write an engine pretty much. If you don't have some really innovative ways that you want to implement in to an engine, I don't see a reason what so ever apart from educating your self to create one. You would have to integrate renderer, input controllers, audio system at minimum. Most engines have been developed for years and have nice features like scene graphs.

4 - box2D is very nice, it has been one of the most commonly used 2d physics engines. There is also Chipmunk but its based on earlier version of Box2d. There is also Nape which is faster then Box2d but its only AC3 from what I know.
5. The physics in Angry Birds have been simulated using Box2d. I don't know what they used for the rest, but some sort of an engine similar to cocos2dx, libgdx etc.

My opinion you should spend a bit of time to evaluate different engines and pick one that suits you. Writing your own is quite a monstrous task. Do not underestimate how much work goes in to creating a commercially viable engine and by that I mean something that you can use to create a game. Use one of the existing ones and learn from them. There is quite a few:

- Moai
- Cocos2d/2dx
- Love
- LibGDX
- Unity 3D ( bit a nightmare to work in 2d, but possible )
- Haxe
- Xamarin
- etc. there is just to many to list them all

Comment: i will be using cocos2dx

Answer (score 0):

No, box2D can't be used "alone". You need something else to, at least, draw on the screen, interact with the user, etc. Box2D only computes the physical part of your game.

So :

1) No

2 / 3) Yes (As long as you repaint your game scene all the time, while updating Box2D)

4) I never tried other libs

5) Don't know.